# Issues with Gnome window management in two display screens

Tags: gnome, window-manager, metacity

I am troubleshooting this GUI application running multiple windows, some of which are small and made explicitly to stay on top of the main window (which usually stays on the first display scree). The problem is, as soon as i take the cursor to the second display screen , the window (which is supposed to stay on top) hides , and i have to (ALT-TAB) to retrieve it.

This problem has nothing to do with GUI application, this rather has to do with window management, because when i open a terminal window on top of the main window , as soon as i take the cursor to the second display window, the terminal window hides.

I heard that Metacity has some fix to this ?
Is there a way to write a bash script to handle this issue, i just don't know how to start ?

Answer (score 0):

Without any info on your environment, perhaps this will help:

http://worldofgnome.org/how-to-set-focus-follows-mouse-in-gnome-3-windows/

Essentially, use the method for your distro to edit this dconf:

org-> gnome-> desktop-> wm-> preferences -> focus-mode

It sounds like when you are moving your mouse, it changes focus away from the window that you want on top.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but the link says that the default-click behavior which is when the mouse clicks over the window, it will focus.

Comment: Btw , my gnome is 2.28 and can't change it ...is the configuration of  "Focus-Follows-Mouse available in the version of Gnome i mentioned.

Comment: Actually, when in the first display screen, the window which supposed to stay on top does not hide as i drag the mouse to the main window (both in the same display screen), this happens only when i move the cursor to the second window.

Comment: When you say hide, do you mean minimize or go behind the focused window? If it's just going behind the focused/primary window, It would mean that moving to the second display is causing the focused window to refocus in front of the secondary window.

Comment: Right your interpretation of "hide" is correct. So how would i change gconf flags to raise or what configuration do i need to make...i'm looking at some  gnome tutorial, but a redirection in the right path to solution is appreciated

Comment: I am not familiar with your specific version of gnome but the best suggestion that I can make would be to check all of the options for 'auto-raise' and 'focus-mode' in org-> gnome-> desktop-> wm-> preferences. Perhaps there is an auto-raise mode that specifically requires a mouse click. There might also be a way to change the behavior of moving the mouse to the second display but I'm not sure where to start there.